# Vespa vs other no-sql databases

Tags: nosql, yahoo-api, vespa

I have been going through Vespa documentation for a while but interested in understanding advantages and disadvantages of vespa over no-sql db's like hbase and cassandra as a key-value store. I don't see any blog/post about it.

1) For hbase,cassandra recommended row size for better performance should not exceed 1MB , 32MB. How about vespa? How large can a vespa document be and what's the recommended size?

2) Where does Vespa fit in CAP theorem?

Answer (score 3):

Vespa is more of an ElasticSearch alternative than an HBase/Cassandra one so while documents can be bigger it isn't the same use case

re 2 - Vespa is CP - as described in [the documentation](https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/content/consistency.html)

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on question 2) re: CAP, Vespa is currently AP (with a caveat, see below), not CP. The C in CAP implies that the linearizability property holds for writes and reads, which is not offered by our existing consistency model. In particular, even though we have a write-ahead log *per replica*, there’s no consistent distributed log *across* replicas.

Note that our “A” in AP is “weak” in the sense that we depend on a centralised (but fault tolerant) cluster coordinator which tracks and communicates the availability of nodes. Nodes that are partitioned away from the coordinator leader are not guaranteed to successfully answer client requests (applies to both reads and writes).

I'll add a section to the linked documentation that explicitly states the CAP properties of Vespa.